# C++ interface error, a non-static member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, interface

i have an interface but i can't use it because methods should be static.. or another solution... as far as i see they cant be static...:

The graphics library that has a definition of the function that it uses:

```
GraphicsLibrary.h
    virtual void drawText(const std::string& text, const Point& pt, unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b);
```

Here just to make it clear, OpenGL that is derived from GraphicsLibrary:

```
OpenGL.h
class OpenGL : public GraphicsLibrary
```

OpenGL.cpp uses the virtual function from GraphicsLibrary and between brackets it "does" things..:

```
OpenGL.cpp 
void GraphicsLibrary::drawText(const std::string& text, const Point &pt, unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b)
{
//does things
}
```

Then im my Main i use the method... but it gives an error

```
MyMain
OpenGL::drawText(toString(mousePos_world), drawPosition, 255, 0, 0);
```

Error: a non-static member reference must be relative to a specific object

---

How should i fix this problem? I read i should make the function static, but i thought i can't... right? Or most people say, think why you made your construction of classes this way that you are using methods of other classes, but that is because i have an interface...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `OpenGL` class:

```
OpenGL ogl;
ogl.drawText(...);
```

Your function `drawText` is a member function of the class, that means it has to be called on an object of that class.  An object is an instance of a specific class.

Then on that object you can call your function.

If you do not wish to create an instance, then you should make your function `static`, upon which you can call it like so:  `OpenGL::drawText(...);`

Answer (score 1):

You just need an instance of `OpenGL` to call it on. Specifically how you do that depends on information about `OpenGL` you haven't given, but it'll look something like this:

```
OpenGL gl;
gl.drawText(toString(mousePos_world), drawPosition, 255, 0, 0);
```

You were attempting to call `drawText` as though it were a static member function (using `::`). Since `drawText` isn't static, you need an object to call it on.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your graphic library object.

```
std::unique_ptr<GraphicsLibrary> pGL(new OpenGL); //or shared_ptr
pGL->drawText(...);
```